# How Reduce the Width of ContentSize in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios6.0

How to Reduce the size of `contentSize` width of `UITableViewCell`.

-> I tried,in `UITableView` property but there had options for reduce the `UITableViewCell` contentSize of Height but not for Width.

-> I want to reduce the `UITableViewCell` contentSize width in `UITableView`.

Comment: i can increase and decrease the height of content cell but i can't decrease the width...

Comment: u have cell class , on that place reduce the width progrmatically

Comment: i tried but didn't work .height could be change but width doesn't?

Comment: http://www2.zippyshare.com/v/wk5fEzMi/file.html
see above pic.this is from tableview.i wanna reduce cell width...

Comment: @Tamil_Arya there is no property of cell like contentCell.. you want to change the cell content size right.

Comment: ya.i wanna change size the cell content but not height i wanna width.

Comment: Thanks for reply,...Ashok Londhe .i got answer,..                                                                      - (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                             self.bounds.origin.y,
                             self.bounds.size.width - 50,
                             self.bounds.size.height);
 
    [super layoutSubviews];
}                                                                                               http://natashatherobot.com/ios-frame-vs-bounds-resize-basic-uitableview-cell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// MyCustomUITableViewCell.m
- (void)layoutSubviews
{

self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y,self.bounds.size.width - 50,self.bounds.size.height);

```
[super layoutSubviews];
```

}
http://natashatherobot.com/ios-frame-vs-bounds-resize-basic-uitableview-cell/'

Answer (score 1):

You can not reduce cell width using cell property. You need to change UITableView frame size. Set width whatever you want to set.

Comment: It's not working if we want to update UITableViewCell frame based on the UITableView contentSize frame and not on UITableView frame?